# Отправка на сервер файла

Tags: php, html, сервер, form, загрузка

Форма

```html
<h2>Форма для загрузки файлов</h2>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000">Send this file:
  <input name="userfile" type="file">
  <button type="submit" value="load">Send</button>
</form>
```

Скрипт

```js
if($_REQUEST['submit'] == 'load'){
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'temp_upload/' . 
        '12345'.'.xlsx')) {
        print "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
    } 
    else {
        print "There some errors!";
    }
}
else 
    echo "!";
```

все в одном файле index.php

Почему не обрабатывается субмит load?всегда вылазит через эхо "!"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы не передаёте на сервер никакого submit, type="submit" не в счет, в форме должно быть поле name="submit".

Добавьте в форму скрытое поле:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="load">
```

Comment: спасибо,понял,исправлюсь=)